# How to share a transaction between repositories?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I use [sqlx](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx) to communicate with my Postgres database. I'm trying to abstract the database communication with a Repository pattern. Aslo, with this abstraction I would like to share the database transaction between repositories using Unit Of Work pattern. The only problem that I have I don't know how to share the `sqlx` transaction between those repositories without explicitly providing `transaction` in `save` arguments (e.g. `repository_x.save(entity, transaction)`). I would like to create and share transactions in `uow` (unit of work) abstraction.

I want to achieve something like this

```rs
struct CommandHandler {
  unit_of_work: UnitOfWork
}

impl CommandHandler {
  pub fn handle(&self, &command: Command) {
    let repository_a = self.unit_of_work.repository_a();
    let repository_b = self.unit_of_work.repository_b();    

    let entity_a = repository_a.get_by_id(command.id);
    let entity_b = repository_b.get_by_id(entity_a.id);


    unit_of_work.start_transaction();

    repository_a.save(entity_a);
    repository_b.save(entity_b);

    unit_of_work.commit_transaction();
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what the implementation of the `unit_of_work` struct would look like to execute the above example?

Comment: Hey @Roman, have you found any solution for this ?
if yes can you please post the answer.

Comment: Hey @DeepakKumar, to sum it up, I couldn't find a solution for this. It appears that sharing transactions between repositories isn't straightforward. You either have to manually pass the transaction object in each method (e.g., `repository_a.save(entity_a, transaction)`), or create a single function that encapsulates the logic from both methods. My personal preference is to avoid using 'general methods' and instead create specific repository methods for each particular case. These methods can encapsulate the logic of interacting with multiple database entities.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply @Roman, yeah there seems to be no solution for now, was going through there github and found it to be an active issue -  https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/419